# Thinking in node if Java background

Tags: java, javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am a Java Developer where everything is working in sequential way (or concurrently with multiple threads), one after another. And it's logical to place things in a sequential way.
But node works in concurrent order with single thread. How it can be beneficial even if it is working only on single thread?

Frankly telling, I didn't get the concept of single thread in node. Only one thread handle everything?

Any advice would be beneficial on how I can start thinking in node.

Comment: ok got -1 please comment so that i can understand what is wrong in my question.
I google and didn't find anything that relate java with node

Comment: you can learn browser javascript.. u will solve your puzzles

Comment: Ok,Can you explain what do you mean by browser javascript?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/

Comment: I know javascript but it is also run in sequential way So how javascript and node different ?

Comment: @squiroid standard javascript in browsers is also asynchronous. It may look sequential, but once you start sending data back and forth, you'll notice it is asynchronous :)  I down-voted you, purely because this question was answered billion times on the web, and thousand times on Stack-overflow.  But hope my answer clears things out for you.

Comment: @alandarev ok suppose i have a server installed with node js (Single thread) if i send multiple login request to it (more than 100) then how node will handle all of them ?(With only one thead).Now consider node will execute them one by one by eventListner but what about the other processing(file read,database,...etc) on the server ?

Comment: Perhaps from a Java perspective to get a better understanding, do some research into the non-blocking IO possibilities of the Java NIO package.

Comment: @Gimby nice i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Synchronous Programming(Java)**

If you  are familiar with synchronous programming (writing code that does one thing after the other) like Java or .Net.  take the following code,
 For example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var content = fs.readFileSync('simpleserver1.js','utf-8');
console.log('File content: ');
console.log(content);
```

It writes out the code for a simple web server to the console. The code works sequentially, executing each line after the next. The next line is not executed until the previous line finishes executing.

Although this works well,

> what if the file in this example were really large and took minutes
>   to read from?
>
> How could other operations be executed while that code or long
>   operation is running?
>   These questions will not arise if you are working in java, because you have many threads to work for you(to serve multiple requests)

---

**Asynchronous Programming(Node.Js)**

But when you are using Node you just have a single thread, which serves all requests.

So there comes asynchronous programming, to help you in javascript(Node)

To execute operations while other long operations are running, we use `function callbacks`. The code below shows how to use an asynchronous callback function:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('simpleserver1.js','utf-8', function(err,data){
       if (err) {
              throw err;
       }
       console.log(“executed from the file finishes reading”);

});
//xyz operation
```

Notice that the line “executed from the file finishes reading” is executed as the file is being read, thus allowing us to **perform other operations** while the main reading of the file is also being executed.

Now look at the `//xyz operation`, in the code. when the file is being read, the server will not wait for the file to be read completely. it will just start executing  `//xyz operation`, and will get back to , the callback function provided in `fs.readFile(`, when the file is ready.

So thats how Asynchronous programming works in Node.

Also if you want to conpare java and Node you can read this [Article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2886368/java-web-development/java-vs-nodejs-an-epic-battle-for-developer-mindshare.html)

---

**EDIT:**

**How is node.Js single Threaded**
lets take a scenario, where clients request server:

> **Assumptions:**
>
> 1) there is single server process, say `serverProcess`,
>
> 2) There are 2 clients requesting server, say `clientA` and `clientB`.
>
> 3) Now, consider clientA, is going to require a file Operation(as one
>   shown above using `fs`).

what happens here,

> **Flow:**
>
> 1) `clientA` requests `serverProcess`, server gets the request, then
>   it starts performing file operation. Now it waits till the file is
>   ready to read(callback is not yet invoked yet).
>
> 2) `clientB` requests `serverProcess`, Now the server is free right
>   now, as it is not serving `clientA`, so it servs `clientB`, in the
>   mean-time, the callback from `fs.read`, Notifies the server that file
>   data is ready, and it can perform operations on it.
>
> 3) Now server starts serving 'clientA'.

now you see, there was just one thread of server , which handled both the client requests, right?

---

Now what would have happened if this was JAVA, you would have created another thread of server for serving `clientB`, while `clientA` was being served by first thread, and waiting for file to be read. So this is how Node is single threaded, meaning A single Process Handles all the requests.

---

**Question:**

> **while there is another process invoked who prepared data from file system, how would you say node is single threaded:**

See, I/O(files/database), is itself a different process, what difference here is,

1) Node does not wait for everything to be ready(like java), instead it will just start its next work(or serve other requests), but whatever happens, **node  will not create a different thread to serve rest of the requests**(unless explicitly done//not recommended though).

2) while **java will create another thread itself for serving new requests.**

Comment: Nice example ,Know  fs.readFile this operation is done by whom ?
I mean if there is only one thread which is handling the request from outside who will do readFile operation?

Comment: yes there ae background processes which will read file for you and make data available, but finally the callback is executed by the main(single) thread only

Comment: So how node is single threaded ?

Comment: @squiroid.. a single thread does each work on your server: when there is **input/output**(this is not a servers work here) then this work is given to background process, and when they come back with result, there is the same process serving them again.. so there is only single process which serves you(all http requests).

Comment: Yes only one thread to process my all request but there are also other threads which helps the main execution thread to work on (I/),Reading,writing) these threads doen't belong to node ?

Comment: @squiroid.. read my updated answer, hope this will make clear to you, how node is single threaded

Comment: Great you are awesome :-)

Answer (score 1):

This has been said million times, but let me give you a short answer with respect to Java.

You create separate Thread in Java if you want to read a long file, without blocking main thread.

In Javascript, you just read the file using callbacks.

Main difference between those two:

1. It is easier to screw up the code with multiple threads (race condition, etc).
2. You do not need exactly the power of CPU's second core to read the file, it is a question of slow I/O, not intensive communication.
3. In callbacks, there is single thread as you said. Though, it just asks underlying system to read the file, and continues executing your code. Once the file is read, then javascript pauses the code it was executing, and will come back to run your Callback.

Sometimes, you also have to do computationally intensive stuff in Javascript. In that case you can spawn a new process - look into [cluster](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/cluster.html) module. But usually, computationally, or I/O heavy operations are already done for you, and you just use them using callbacks.

Comment: So i have one thread for listing and other for actual reading or writing stuff so how can it be single threaded ?

Comment: It's not really true that it's easier to screw up multithreaded code, if each thread serves its own isolated request. It is actually callback-based code which makes things difficult because the unit of work is splintered into bits and pieces. You lose simple stack-based scoping of locals, global error handling becomes a pain, memory leaks become much more likely due to all the callback registration/deregistration, etc.

Comment: A fact from the industry is that a significant majority of Java EE professionals actually have no idea about concurrent programming, even though they spend every day writing code which will be executed concurrently.

Comment: haha that's the actual fact even i never tried too much threads during programming (may be springs use internal muliple threads by itself).

Comment: @squiroid Sure thing, Spring-based server-side applications routinely use hundreds, even thousands of threads, on which they run the code *you* wrote. But one entire request, from entry point to the final return value, is served in one go on a single thread---that's why you don't need to know about concurrency. You just need to respect the best practices (stateless singletons etc.)

Comment: So moving towards node from java is a good decision or i just learn basics of node and use it for I/O purpose while creating application and stick with JAVA:-)

Comment: @squiroid different languages, different purposes. I hope banks will never switch from Java to Node. On the other hand, a start-up trying to build a product using Java EE without endless pool of money is doomed too. Done right, assembly will beat anything, but one needs to consider practicality and costs.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Theories are good. But if there is only one thing I learned from the university - people cannot write parallel code.

Comment: The same people can't write callback-based code, either. Both have difficulties and pitfalls. Anyway, university is not exactly the best place to form conclusions about software professionals.

Answer (score 1):

Ok giving you a head start. It is not about threads its about tasks per second. In a thread mode threads block when they wait for something.

In a non-blocking design everytime you wait for something you just give the thread back and be awaken if the event you are waiting for occured. Those events are known as future. So as in the future i want to do this when this and that has happend (or in a failure case do this other thing). Thats basically it.

It is not node or javascript. It is famous for scala too and sure there are plenty of other languages. And if you are a Java guy look for async processing. Jetty provides it. Vertx is famous for a share nothing architecture.

So have fun with this. I use it regularly. I have a server storing 20GB of data in a custom datastore. Wanna know how we scaled? We brought 512GB for the server and did 20 of those stores in parallel sharing nothing. Its like having 20 servers in one machine with no noticable latency and you scale with the cores. Thats how we do business in todays world.

Hardware is cheap so why fiddle with concurrency on the lowest level?

Comment: And yes I use java for it... its all about you.

Comment: So node is not replacement of java for backend it' just use for I/O purpose ?

Comment: Nope. It is one of the more prominent frameworks (accidently written in JavaScript) for the non-blocking async request processing. In the java world we have other frameworks. So it is also not for IO purposes.

Comment: So using java without multiple threads and with callback  can be similar to node ?

Comment: Once the Async movement accellerated Java got Servlet 3.x specification also allowing several things to process it in parallel. So take a look around. Check vertx for example. It is a good programming model.